# Get multiple Objects from JList and add them to an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, jlist

I'm having trouble with this part of my assignment.

> This panel also contains a JList object containing the following 10 Canadian universities: Toronto, York, Western, Brock, Guelph, Waterloo, McGill, Concordia, Laval and Macmaster. From that list the user will select 3 universities. A Button labeled "Submit" displayed at the bottom of the panel allows the user to enter the input data coming from textfields and JList object into an array with maximum 100 Student objects.

I have created a String Array for 10 universities.

```
  String uniNames[] = {"Toronto", "York", "Western", "Brock", 
     "Guelph", "Waterloo", "McGill", "Concordia", "Laval", "Macmaster"};
```

That Array of Strings is added to a JList

```
  JList<String> uniList = new JList<>(uniNames); //(2)
  uniList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
  uniList.setFixedCellHeight(34);
  uniList.setFixedCellWidth(300);
  uniList.setSelectionMode(
     ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
  //Add to uniPanelList
  uniPanelList.add(uniList);
  //Add to uniPanel
  uniPanel.add(label3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  uniPanel.add(uniPanelList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I have created the Submit button, which takes input data

```
  submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent submit){
        String name = "", mark = "";
        int markNum;
        if (submit.getSource()==submitButton){ //If submit is pressed
           name = nameInput.getText(); 
           mark = markInput.getText();
           markNum = Integer.parseInt(mark); //Convert String to int


           //copyList.setListData(colorList.getSelectedValues());
           //String objs = uniList.getSelectedValuesList();


           //Add information to Array, count++ to keep track
           stuArray[count++] = new Student (name, markNum);
           nameInput.setText(""); //Resets input area
           markInput.setText(""); //Resets input area
           //Set label under submit button
           outputLabel.setText("Student " + count + 
              " out of 100 submitted.");
        }
     }
  });
```

I'm having trouble with the part where the program has to select 3 from my JList, press Submit and it goes into the Array. I have tried getSelectedValuesList(), but it returns an error.

List cannot be converted to String
               String objs = uniList.getSelectedValuesList();

I'm stuck trying to figure out where to go on from here. Any tips?

Comment: try String objs  = uniList.getSelectedValue().toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [toArray() function of java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--) might be what you're looking for. According to the Javadoc:

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
>   sequence.

```
submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent submit) {
        String[] selectedUniversities = uniList.getSelectedValuesList().toArray(new String[] {});
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution worked wonderfully, thank you!

I ended up finding another solution, but uses the depreciated method getSelectedValues(), but the getSelectedValuesList() with the toArray() function is much more simple!


                  Object[] selectedUni = uniList.getSelectedValues();  
                  String[] selectedUniString = new String[selectedUni.length];  
                  for (int i = 0; i < selectedUni.length; i++){ 
                     selectedUniString[i] = selectedUni[i].toString();

Answer (score 0):

The error message states all you need:

***List cannot be converted to String***

do instead:

```
String objs = uniList.getSelectedValue().toString();
```